# Open fancybox via regular text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

On my website, a fancy box popup shows up after a few seconds asking the user if he wants to register to the newsletter. That works fine.

However I would also like to put a link on the page that would open-up the newsletter box. I've tried `Click <a href="#newsletterpopup">here</a> to open the popup`. without success.

See http://jsfiddle.net/PQqGC/1/

Many thanks for your help

JS:

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fancybox('#newsletterpopup', {
            closeClick: false, // this prevents fancybox to close unless close unless ".non-merci" is clicked
            showCloseButton: true,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
                    }
                }
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                // enables a way to close fancybox
                $(".non-merci").on("click", function () {
                    $.fancybox.close()
                });
            }
        });
    }, 7000);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0.04
    });
});
```

Non-related script that could potentially cause conflict with the click function:

```
//==============
//! Smooth scrolling / click potentially conflicting with other scripts
//==============

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function (ev) { // Added 'ev' parameter
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            ev.preventDefault(); // We're animating this, so don't let the browser try to navigate to this URL
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 'normal');
        }
    }
});


window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
function scrollFunction() {
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    if (top > 200) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is showing error `undefined is not a function`. Try to correct it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your script:

First you need to add a selector to your link

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#newsletterpopup">here</a>
```

... so you can bind that selector to a regular fancybox initialization like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // options
});
```

Second, your `openFancybox()` function won't open fancybox programmatically but it will trigger a `click` event on the already initialized fancybox selector like

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".fancybox").trigger("click");
    }, 7000);
};
```

In that way you cover both of your needs : fire fancybox after some seconds and having a link to manually open the newsletter

**EDIT** : Fixed bug in jsfiddle

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKh9e/1/)**

Comment: Thanks JFK. I've tried to implement it but for some reason it doesn't work in live environment, see http://goo.gl/aiUGDv I guess that there's probably some conflicting scripts in scripts.js where I have included you code?

Comment: Oops, JFK , I spoke to fast, it doesn't work this page: http://goo.gl/cZgzqq (scroll down to the button, the link is just under the form button). Any idea what is creating a conflict? Thanks

Comment: Check that your `scrollTop` script is not blocking fancybox (it has a `preventDefault()` function)

Answer (score 1):

I put the fancybox declaration in a separate function so it can be called from within your timer and the click event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PQqGC/3/

Lines 3 and 46 call your fancybox code.

** I had to comment out your `cookie` code since the library isn't loaded.